# CRM Online 2013 Email Router Configuration with Office 365 on Cloud

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online, email-router

I want configure Email Router for my CRM online 2013 with Office 365 in Cloud.

Please note: I don't have any on-premise Server for the Email Router Installation steps given on below link:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2708706

Though I have downloaded Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 E-mail Router , CRM2013-Router-KB2891271-LangID-amd64.exe

When I am trying to install this above exe file to install this Email Router on my standalone computer, windows 8.1, it gives me below error.

[image]

I have checked my Outlook, it is all set for the Default programs. Also I followed below article -

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951401/en-us

But It says that you cannot install this components with Microsoft Outlook.

Now, I don't know what to do for setting up the Incoming and Outgoing Email Functionality for my Microsoft Dynamics CRM online 2013 with Office 365 in cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no one has commented yet I thought i'd give it a shot. Unfortunately I haven't had to do it myself as of yet however one of the big benefits of CRM 2013 was meant to be that you could do without the Email Router.

Have you looked into this?

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/crm-customer-center/email-processing-through-server-side-synchronization.aspx

Regardless of the above if you are using Outlook you shouldn't need the Email Router anyway as you can just configure CRM for Outlook

http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=40344

Finally make sure you are reading information about CRM 2013 NOT CRM 2011 as things like the Outlook client have changed for 2013 and we have found the 2011 connector doesn't work and we had to uninstall the old and install the new.